# Input strings in array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, arrayofstring

The problem is that I don't actually know hot to deal with array of pointers, the way I do it, it pass to the position of the array the address, and so I got always in every position, the last input. But if I use the *operator, it only pass the first character.. so how I do it??

```
int main( void ) {

    void prompt_str( const char *str[], char *const copy ); //prototype

    const char *str[ 20 ]= { '\0' };
    const char *copy= 0;

    //prompt stringa
    prompt_str( str, &copy );

} //end main

void prompt_str( const char *str[], char *const copy ) { //definition

    size_t n_str= 0, i= 0;

    do {
        printf( "Insert a string\n:" );
        fgets( copy, 100, stdin );
        i= ( strlen( copy )- 1 ); //get length
        copy[ i ]= '\0'; //remove \n

        str[ n_str++ ]= copy; //put string into pointer of array

    } while ( n_str< 3 );

}
```

Comment: You don't have room to store the input, `const char *copy= 0;` --> `char copy[100];`

Comment: Ok you are right, good luck storing 100 bytes into an address :)

Comment: @KeineLust so the problem could be, that is not a good solution, cause I can loose some of my input?? Can you explain better what you just said?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of the pointer concept.

When you do

```
const char *copy= 0;
```

you only get a `pointer`. You don't get any memory for holding a string.

You can do

```
char copy[100];
```

instead. This will give you memory for holding a string (less than 100 characters). Further you can use `copy` as-if it is a pointer when calling a function.

Alternatively you can use dynamic memory like:

```
char* copy = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));  // Allocate memory

// ... code

free(copy);  // Release memory
```

Comment: it's not true.. infact when I debug, copy has the string I input in it. if I input "ciao", copy has "ciao", but, when I pass it to str, if I pass like in the code above, it's a pass by reference, so everytime I change copy, change the whole str. This is my problem, I want to pass whole copy by value. Just try my code and you'll see it.

Comment: @dnt994 Oh, yes it is true... Have you checked the warnings from the compiler? You have `incompatible pointer type` in the function call. BTW: Both "Keine Lust" and I have tried to help but instead of taking our input seriously, you just claim us to be wrong. Why?